# zuul return 302 with location header

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I have a simple use case, where I need to send 302 HTTP status with the `Location` header if the request comes to the gateway when the url contains **/logout**. This has to happen without routing to the back-end service.

Below is my zuul fillter:

```
public class LogoutFillter extends ZuulFilter{

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {         
        if(RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getRequest().getRequestURI().toLowerCase().contains("/logout")){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "pre";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();        
        HttpSession excistingSession = context.getRequest().getSession(false);
        if(excistingSession != null){
            excistingSession.invalidate();
            context.unset()
            //context.addZuulResponseHeader("Location", "/abc/def/logout.do"); //notworking
            context.setResponseStatusCode(302);         
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have tried to do this like below:

```
HttpServletResponse response = context.getResponse();
response.setStatus(302)
response.setHeader("Location", "/abc/logout.to");
context.unset();
context.setResponse(response);
```

However, that didn't work either. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to resolve the issue. Below is my code

```
@Override
public Object run() {
    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

    HttpSession excistingSession = context.getRequest().getSession(false);
    if(excistingSession != null){
        excistingSession.invalidate();  
        context.setSendZuulResponse(false);
        context.addZuulResponseHeader("Location", "/abc/def/logout.do");
        context.setResponseStatusCode(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
    }
    return null;
}
```

In the above code `setSendZuulResponse(false)` will stop the routing to the back-end service, and the `addZuulResponseHeader` will add the response header.